# How to add an object in array on parsed JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, object, addition

I have this file .json:

```json
{
  "topologyTypes": {
    "stations": {
      "instances": [
        {
          "@name": "value1",
          "@address": "value2"
        },
        {
          "@name": "value3",
          "@address": "value4"
        }         
      ]
    }
  },
  "agg": {},
  "inter": {}
}
```

I want to add an object like this in topologyType.stations.instances with PowerShell

```json
{
    "@name": "value4",
    "@adress": "value5"
}
```

So I tried this following code in PowerShell, but it doesn't work:

```bsh
$path = "./data.json"
$jsonFile = Get-Content $path -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$jsonContent = @"
    {
        "@name": "value4",
        "@adress": "value5"
    }
"@

$jsonFile.topologyTypes.stations.instances |
    Add-Content -Value (ConvertFrom-Json $jsonContent)
```

The desired output I would like to get is like this:

```json
{
  "topologyTypes": {
    "stations": {
      "instances": [
        {
          "@name": "value1",
          "@address": "value2"
        },
        {
          "@name": "value3",
          "@address": "value4"
        },
        {
          "@name": "value4",
          "@address": "value5"
        }         
      ]
    }
  },
  "agg": {},
  "inter": {}
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. How *exactly* does it "not work"? Are you getting an error? What is the expected and actual result? At first glance I can spot at least one PowerShell and one JSON syntax error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I got this error :

 
ConvertFrom-Json : invalid json primitive : [.
(system.argunment.exception)
+ ... ations.instances | Add-Content -Value (ConvertFrom-Json $jsonContent)
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: Because the trailing comma in `$jsonContent` makes the JSON string invalid. But even if you remove it, you can't insert the new data into the JSON structure by appending to a file. Even the original JSON string you posted is invalid. Please [edit] your question show a [mcve] of your code, the input, the desired output, and the arror that code gives you.

Comment: Ok so i modified my first post sorry.. Im not good with the syntax of json file

Comment: maybe just string replace `[` with `[` + `$jsonContent` before parsing it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the new content as a PowerShell custom object:

```
$jsonContent = [PSCustomObject]@{
    '@name'   = 'value4'
    '@adress' = 'value5'
}
```

append it to the `instances` substructure of your imported JSON data:

```
$jsonFile.topologyTypes.stations.instances += $jsonContent
```

then convert the data back to a JSON string:

```
$jsonFile | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```

Note that `ConvertTo-Json` inserts a lot of intention space. If you want exactly the format you posted you need to do some pretty-printing yourself. Something like [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2736) might help.